# Concatenate output/variable from for loop to each element in list

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, concatenation, nested-loops

I have a script that currently builds an empty list from raw_input() on a while loop. (has to be run on server currently with python2.7 hence raw_input)

Next part of script opens & reads a csv file followed by a for loop to manipulate that data using if/else statements, then outputs the newly formatted data assigned to a variable.

I then would like to call this variable outside the loop and apply it (concatenate) to each element of the previously built list. However, this is where the problem is experienced. Whenever calling this variable outside the for loop to concatenate to list elements, it only uses the last line of data from the csv file.

**Context & Intended Flow:** this script's function is to generate IPv6 addresses by combining the v6 subnet/prefix to the MAC addresses contained in the CSV. User inputs the v6 prefix via input which builds the list. After list is complete, the script opens MAC address csv file, formats MAC  then assigns formatted MAC to a variable. Script will take that variable, iterate through v6 prefix list and apply/concatenate to each element.

this is what i currently have;;

```
import csv

subnet_list=[]

#while loop occurs to build list above by user input.
#opens csv and reads MAC addresses

#formats MAC
for address in mac_addy_file:
        mac= address
        colon= ':'
        
        text1= mac[0]

        if mac[1] == '0':
                text2= slaac_table['0']
        elif mac[1] == '1':
                text2= slaac_table['1']

        #...(not in code but continue with conditionals)

        else:
                text2= 'ERROR'

        text3= mac[3:5]
        text4= mac[6:8]
        text5= 'FF'
        text6= 'FE'
        text7= mac[9:11]
        text8= mac[12:14]
        text9= mac[15:]

        new_mac= text1+text2+text3+colon+text4+text5+colon+text6+text7+colon+text8+text9

#loops through v6 prefix list to concat new_mac variable

for subnet in subnet_list:  
    prefix= subnet
    v6= prefix + new_mac
    print(v6)
```

As a simplified example lets say the list is `subnet_list= ['100' , '101']` and the manipulated data of csv file is;

```
11A
22B
```

the current output with the script above is;

```
10022B
10122B
```

but the desired output is;

```
10011A
10022B
10111A
10122B
```

My issue is the script will not use all the formatted MAC addresses of csv file to output all the variations of the IPv6 addresses concatenated from each list  element. It will only output the v6 addresses generated from the last MAC address of the file (last line of csv file) to each list element.

I believe the issue is the second for loop introduced. I have attempted introduce another while loop with no luck and suspect a function maybe an easier way to do this, but not sure how to go about it.

Any insight or advice would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to work out the `new_mac` for each individual subnet. It's probably best to put that into a separate function. Then, you can just call `prefix + new_mac(subnet)` or whatever inputs it requires.

Comment: Hey Robby, thanks for the response. So question, when you say "best to put that into a separate function" what part are you referring to? Just the variable ```new_mac``` and its concatenation or  ```new_mac``` and the second for-loop ```for subnet in subnet_list``` all together as one function?

Comment: I meant: the entire first for loop.